# wp_editor api not writing p tags in custom user profile field

Tags: wordpress

I am building a custom biography field in the wordpress user profile page using WP's wp_editor api (using WP version 3.3.1).

When I add any content though, the WSYIWYG editor is not writing the paragraph tags to the database.

I am able to use the visual editor to add all other mark-up (bold, italics, etc) & I can manually add paragraph tags and save the full marked-up text to the database.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Code I'm using to build the custom field in the functions.php file below.

```
//ADD EXTRA FIELDS TO USER PROFILE
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_profile_fields' );
function extra_profile_fields( $user ) {

    //CHECK FOR AUTHOR BIO CONTENT  
    $check_for_bio = get_the_author_meta('authorbio', $user->ID);
    $author_bio = '';
    if (!empty($check_for_bio)) { $author_bio = $check_for_bio; } 

    //BUILD THE INPUT
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th><label for="authorbio">Author Biography</label></th>';
            echo '<td>';
            $settings = array('wpautop' => true, 'media_buttons' => false);
            wp_editor( $author_bio, 'authorbio', $settings);        
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';    
}

//SAVE EXTRA FIELDS TO USER PROFILE
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'authorbio', $_POST['authorbio'] );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved the issue. Was not adding the_content fitler. When printing the output.

```
<?php
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Answer (score 1):

For PHP dummies like I am, this is a possible way how to create an ouput:

```
<?php 
    $bio_czech = get_the_author_meta('bio_czech',$user->ID);
    echo wpautop($bio_czech);
?>
```